# What does a dot do in CSS, in relation to HTML5?

Tags: html, css

Is the dot a way to define a class that can be cited in the later HTML? and would the  be a reverse of that from HTML to CSS?

For example in the CSS:

```
.page {
   styling options;}
```

and in the following HTML:

```
<div class="page">
<page content>
```

Comment: I would suggest you start with the very beginnings: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKoajPPWpmo. Search for some additional resources, like CodeAcademy, Udacity, etc etc. Find some stuff to follow so you get started.

Comment: if you don't know what a `.` do in CSS then read about CSS ... this is the first thing you will learn in any basic CSS tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Simple_selectors).

The concept of 'defining' classes doesn’t really make sense. Classes are a way of putting a 'marker' on an element so that it can be referenced in CSS. There is no penalty for using a class in HTML that isn’t referenced in CSS, or vice versa.